# Afnetworking wrong block is returned

Tags: objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2

I am using `afnetworking` and `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`,
I have a singleton class, which contains all my api call. However, when I have concurrent *api* call, wrong data is being returned. API call A is returning API call B response?

`CHAFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is a subclass of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`

Anyone experience the same problem, what do I need to do to solve this:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@/profile_photo", userName];
   CHAFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [CHAFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManagerObj];
[manager GET:path
   parameters:nil
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        }
      ];
     }
```